# How do I make the Discord bot reply in "Embed" form in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot reply in embed form when its mentioned, So far this is my code but it sends an error in my terminal and of course it does nothing.

```
    client.on('messageCreate',message=>{
    if(client.user && message.content === `<@!${client.user.id}>`){
        const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
    var embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('WELCOME')
    .setAuthor('null')
    .setDescription('HELLO BOIIII')
    message.reply(embed)
    }
})
```

When I put `content: 'string'`  in the `message.reply({})` it works. but how do I make the message sent embed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an embed you need to do:

```js
message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
```

In your case

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('WELCOME')
    .setAuthor('null')
    .setDescription('HELLO BOIIII')
    message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
 }
```